# MS Chart X Axis label repeated - showing multiple points for a single item [Range Bar]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, data-binding, mschart

I have created a RangeBar MS Chart control that binds with a datatable. This datatable is created based on the below list data. 
 The problem is that x axis is showing multiple points for same item with different range. 


**List**
[image]

**MS Chart**
X axis represents the 1st column of the list and Y axis values are 3rd and 4th columns. "dt" is the datatable name

[image]

**Code**

```
chChart.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar;
chChart.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBind(dt.DefaultView, "Number", "Start Time,Stop Time","ToolTip=Name,Label=Name");
```

Tried binding as different series but still not working.

```
  var IETable = (dt as System.ComponentModel.IListSource).GetList();
             chChart.DataBindCrossTable(IETable, "Number", "Number", "Start Time,Stop Time","");

                foreach (Series sr in chChart.Series)
                {
                    sr.ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar;
                    sr.YValueType = ChartValueType.Time;

                    sr.XValueType = ChartValueType.String;


                }
```

**Is there a way to group x axis value for same item so that the bars are in same line?**

Note - When using custom labels, only one value is shown for each x axis label.

Comment: You could try pulling all the data first into a more managable form and then adding it back into the chart, chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(...) for labels and the same for x axis. You would need to post a bit more with what you are working for

Comment: @Vajura I have edited my question for more clarity.

Comment: You say that X axis is the first column(zzz-2 etc) but on the graph on the picture its on the Y axis (vertical axis = y axis). And you dont do anything with the second column?

Comment: @Vajura : In case of "RangeBar" chartype, x axis is the vertical one and y axis is the horizontal one. No, i am not using the second column in the list.

Comment: To put bars on a same row, all the values must be in separate series

Comment: Oh yes, it was actually a StackedBar which I once used to mimic the behaviour of RangeBar. But I wrote an Answer for you about how to do it with the RangeBar.

Comment: @Jaska Thanks. Will update soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Add 1 `Series` into the chart. Then for the Series, make sure `YValuesPerPoint = 2`.
Add new `DataPoints` so that the `XValue` represents the line (in the example for line ABC1, `XValue = 1` and line ABC2, `XValue = 2`. For the `DataPoint.AxisLabel` you can set the label of that axis (in this case 'ABC1' and 'ABC2'). Then for the `YValues`, you specify values comma separated, for example `1,2` or `7,20`.

Example:

```
        chChart.Series["Series1"].Points.Add(new DataPoint() { AxisLabel = "ABC1", XValue = 1, YValues = new double[] { 2,5 } });
        chChart.Series["Series1"].Points.Add(new DataPoint() { AxisLabel = "ABC1", XValue = 1, YValues = new double[] { 6,7 } });
        chChart.Series["Series1"].Points.Add(new DataPoint() { AxisLabel = "ABC1", XValue = 1, YValues = new double[] { 9,10 } });

        chChart.Series["Series1"].Points.Add(new DataPoint() { AxisLabel = "ABC2", XValue = 2, YValues = new double[] { 3,6 } });
        chChart.Series["Series1"].Points.Add(new DataPoint() { AxisLabel = "ABC2", XValue = 2, YValues = new double[] { 7,8 } });
```

So the key is that the `XValue` must be same (double?) for all the bars on same line.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I had to manipulate datapoints individually for each series. Based on the index of the custom label, i modified the Xvalue of the datapoint.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating datapoints individually for each series did the trick. Based on the index of the custom label, i modified the Xvalue of the datapoint. "vn" is a string array that has custom label names.

```
var IETable = (dt as System.ComponentModel.IListSource).GetList();
chChart.DataBindCrossTable(IETable, "Number","","Start Time,StopTime","");

                  foreach (Series sr in chChart.Series)
                  {

                      sr.ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar;
                      sr.XValueType = ChartValueType.String;
                      foreach (DataPoint p in sr.Points)
                      {
                          int dpIndex=0;
                          // foreach unique x axis value, increment dpIndex
                          //ToDoCode

                         //aligning the datapoint's X axis value in the middle

                          p.XValue = dpIndex + 0.5;

                      }

                  }
```